# Sencha-Touch to Android - TouchWiz issue

Tags: android, apk, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd, sencha-command

I am new to Android and I have just build my first apk file.
My app is is actually a Sencha-Touch-Web-App packaged for Andoird by Sencha CMD.

Samsung user interface TouchWiz stops when I install the app on my device with adb. Which makes the device unusable. TouchWiz works back when I uninstall the app.

I don't see how my javascript code could be responsible for this error. Do you agree with me ?

Below the json file that configures the Sencha CMD packaging operation :

```
{
    "applicationName":"TheName",
    "applicationId":"com.mevena.myAppID",   
    "bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",
    "versionString":"1.0-alpha",
    "versionCode":"1",
    "icon": {
        "36":"resources/icons/icon36.png",
        "48":"resources/icons/icon48.png",
        "57":"resources/icons/icon72.png"
    },
    "inputPath":"./",
    "outputPath":"../build",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",   
    "certificatePath":"./la-clef.keystore",
    "certificateAlias":"la-clef",
    "certificatePassword":"thePassword",
    "provisionProfile":"",
    "notificationConfiguration":"",
    "sdkPath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk",
    "androidAPILevel":"14",
    "permissions":[
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "CAMERA",
        "VIBRATE",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CALL_PHONE"
    ],
    "orientations": [
        "portrait"
    ]
}
```

Any clue about the TouchWiz issue origin would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Does only the TouchWiz launcher crash or the whole system?
Maybe you can check this using an alternate launcher (e.g. "nova launcher" or "pro launcher").

After some googling it seems that `sencha touch 2.1` Seems to have some problems on different vendor specific UIs and launchers. Maybe you should contact their support.

If nothing seems to work, you should maybe exclude Galaxy devices or check for touchwiz.
Does your code work on other devices using other UIs like HTC Sense, Motorola Blur or Sony Timescape?